# inject javascript into page which loads in childbrowser phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cookies, browser

I have a link which opens in the child browser of phonegap - for those not familiar with phonegap just think of it as a new window.

The link that I am opening has an annoying alert which pops up the 1st time the webpage is loaded on the device. I would like to stop this alert poping up by trying to change the cookie the webpage uses to check if it has been loaded before.

1. Is this possible?
2. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: looks like this is not possilbe as a page containing an iframe can't interact with anything within the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

Little Difficult.
You could host your own html page remotely and enclose the page you are opening inside a iFrame which you could stop the alerts by some type of javascript. Or (using ajax) remotely retrieve the page you are after?

Comment: I've found a related.. similar question as well.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15212824/how-can-i-open-an-iframe-in-a-phonegap-cordova-app-running-on-ios?rq=1