# How to open an external page inside a ion-content in ionic2

Tags: angular, iframe, ionic2

I need to create an app that open external pages inside the app in Ionic2.

I've tried **InAppBrowser** component, but it only open sites in external pages or replacing all app content.

I've also tried Iframes, but I would like to know id it's possible to use the **InAppBrowser** component to open the external site content in a `ion-content` tag?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with external page?

Comment: A site like google or facebook, open its content, (assuming it's authorized) inside my app.

Comment: check this answer, I think it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/15390944/3243642